# Cómo hacer que un slider tenga la opción 'touch' para moviles

Tags: drupal, slider, touch

Tengo un slider en drupal con sus flechitas para cambiar de slider, pero cuando lo hago responsive para móviles tengo la opción de las flechitas para mover de una imagen a otra, pero me gustaría tener la opción de pasar de slider a slider con el dedo. Hay alguna manera de hacerlo mediante css?

Gracias

Comment: Hola Sil, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Qué slider? ¿versión? ¿versión de Drupal? ¿Es del theme o es un módulo? Por otro lado, si el slider no cuenta con esa opción, deberás implementarla tu mismo. Para implementarlo en Drupal, debes usar módulos, puedes crear uno tu mismo y usar los ganchos apropiados para realizar lo que pides.